# How do relations work in MeteorJS/Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

and am not sure where to find this in the docs. How can I add more objects to the User object?

For instance if I run 
`meteor add accounts`

and I get a full user collection with a working user login/signup template. I would like to add a posts collection/object inside this users collection, so that users can only view there own posts.

So how can I add each post to the current users object?

Answer (score 1):

You can add users to the Meteor.users collection by adding `accounts-password` package. Use  `Accounts.createUser()` method to create new users.

Find the documentation here: https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser

Answer (score 1):

Meteor.users is a handle to users collection in Meteor. You can use it just as any other collection AKA

```
Meteor.users.findOne(id) 
or 
Meteor.users.update(...)
```

And of course you can't add posts collection to user collection. These will be different collections.

Storing objects in MongoDB under users collection document is pretty straight forward:

```
Meteor.users.update(
    { _id: userId }, 
    { $set: { objectFieldName: { a: 1, b: 2 }}}
)
```

Or if you need to do it on user create you should user [Accounts package hooks](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html).

Comment: so in my Template.body.helpers where I have a method called posts(){} how can I return the posts related to that specific user?

Comment: @MkrJs read some [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/) and [meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/) please! You will definitely find info you are looking for there.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching it wrong. Use pub/subs to achieve this.

When you insert a post, have a field called userId or ownerId

```
//inside Meteor.methods() on server side
Posts.insert({
    owner: Meteor.userId(),
    //some other fields
});
```

Then in your publication, return only the Posts that the user owns

```
//publication on server side
//checks if the visitor is a user
//if user, returns that user's posts
Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
    if (this.userId) {
        return Posts.find({owner: this.userId})
    }
});
```

Then subscribe to the publication. No parameters needed:

```
//client side
Meteor.subscribe('posts')
```